# SQL Select Statement (If column matches value) As ColumnName

Tags: sql

***Sample Data:***

Table: PollingSettings

Example rows:

```
ID | Frequency      | Value
---+----------------+-------
 1 | Frequency      | 300
 1 | Timeout        | 500
 2 | Frequency      | 1200
 2 | Timeout        | 100
 3 | LogFilesToKeep | 30
 3 | DebugEnabled   | False
```

I need a select statement that will do something along the lines:

```
 SELECT ID, key as Frequency, key as Timeout

 CASE Freqency
      WHEN Frequency = 'Frequency' THEN value
 CASE Timeout
      WHEN Timeout = 'Timeout' THEN value
 END
 FROM PollingSettings
```

Essentially, I need to create two new columns called timeout and frequency, but only if the ID has a key column with the value of either 'frequency' or 'timeout' and call the column either 'frequency' or 'timeout' with the value from the key value pair. Otherwise, those columns should still be created, they should just be set to 'null'. The end result being something like this:

```
ID | Frequency   | Timeout
---+-------------+-------
 1 | 300         | 500
 2 | 1200        | 100
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create two columns that have case statements, and get the max value so you only get 1 line per ID:

```
select ID, 
    max(case when key='Frequency' then value end) as Frequency,
    max(case when key='Timeout' then value end) as Timeout
from PollingSettings
group by ID
```

Comment: @user10318153 since this answer was posted first you should accept it.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I think since it was an easy one we were both typing at the same time. Although fa06 left out the max() when first posted so I let mine stand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT ID, min(CASE WHEN key = 'Frequency' THEN value end) as Frequency,
 min(CASE WHEN key = 'Timeout' THEN value end) as Timeout
 FROM PollingSettings group by ID
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed - thank you for the quick reply... I probably should have asked this an hour ago before it was frustrating... :)

Comment: Got it, sorry - first time posting here. Had just up-voted. Thank you!

Comment: There is still an extra END in your answer.